# How can I replace the ISBN with the Google Books ID in a MARC file, using Perl?

Tags: perl, isbn, google-books, marc

I've got a file with some book data in [MARC](http://www.loc.gov/marc/bibliographic/) format, of which some lines are ISBNs. I'd like to replace these lines with the Google Books ID of that ISBN, if it exists. Here's the code so far, which just ends up removing the lines:

`perl -pe "s#ISBN(.*)#$(wget --output-document=- --quiet --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 \"http://books.google.com/books?jscmd=viewapi&bibkeys=\1\")#mg" < 5-${file} > 6-${file}`

PS: Google are a bit fuzzy on the use of automated tools: The [Books Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#Audience) recommends tools like curl / wget, but there are no instructions on how to avoid being blocked when using such tools. I'm also pretty sure I saw a clause in a ToS saying users can't send automated queries, but I can't find it again. This is [discussed](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/booksearch-apis/thread?tid=299354bc3ebf6b4a) in their forum.

Comment: Do you insist on a oneliner for this job?

Comment: Not really - I realized that \1 is not replaced until after the command is run, so this approach does not work. Building a Perl script now.

Comment: consider using something like LWP::Simple instead of calling wget.

Comment: What would the resulting line of your output look like? From the URL you use I get a JavaScript snippet. Do you want all of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the OP is on the right track and could use a one-liner for this, and just needs to replace some bash-style syntax with the correct Perl syntax. I think this would work (newlines added for readability):

```
    perl -pe 's#ISBN(\w+)#qx(wget --output-document=- 
        --quiet --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 
        "http://books.google.com/books\\?jscmd=viewapi\\&bibkeys=$1")#ge' \
        < 5-${file} > 6-${file}
```

You have to escape (edit: double escaping seems to work) the `$` or `&` characters in the url.

Comment: I think using the fake user agent is in violation of Google's TOS. Without it: `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: This replaces the ISBN with a big gob of JavaScript, doesn't it? Am I missing some magic or something?

Answer (score 5):

The reason you end up having to lie about the user agent is because you are violating Google's TOS: Don't do that.

Instead, use the [Google Book Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#SearchingForBooks).

The code below is slightly hampered by my lack of familiarity with modules such as [XML::Atom](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Atom), [Data::Feed](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Atom), [WWW::OpenSearch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::OpenSearch). However, it should provide a good starting point.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Business::ISBN qw( valid_isbn_checksum );
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Simple;

while ( <> ) {
    s/ISBN:([0-9]+)/'Google Books ID:' . get_google_id_for_isbn($1)/ge;
    print;
}

use Carp;

sub make_google_books_query {
    sprintf 'http://books.google.com/books/feeds/volumes?q=isbn:%s', $_[0];
}

sub get_google_id_for_isbn {
    my ($isbn) = @_;

    my $google_id = eval {
        defined(valid_isbn_checksum $isbn)
            or croak "Invalid ISBN: $isbn";

        my $query = make_google_books_query($isbn);
        my $xml = get $query;

        defined($xml)
            or croak "No response to <$query>";

        my $data = XMLin($xml, ForceArray => 1);
        my @ids = @{ $data->{entry}[0]{'dc:identifier'} };

        unless ("ISBN:$isbn" eq $ids[1]
                or "ISBN:$isbn" eq $ids[2] ) {
            croak "Invalid search results: '@ids'";
        }

        $ids[0];
    };

    defined($google_id) ? $google_id : '';
}
```

Given a text file `t.txt` containing:

```
ISBN:0060930314
ISBN:9780596520106
```

it outputs:

```
Google Books ID:ioXFqlzsmK8C
Google Books ID:lNVHi3TunxsC
```

Comment: Also, see my Business::ISBN module if you want to validate the incoming ISBNs. Google returns results even for invalid input. You might also want to wrap an eval around @{ ... } in case there is no entry.